# Get data from input and on submit button clicked console log the data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to send emailwith data when user input his name,email,subject,text,telephone.this email is sent to email like email@gmail.com a particular email in my case the web site is for hotel so the email of the hotel.
The following code isnt working and it  doesnt show any data on "#submit" button click. I cant find the reason that it's not working.It is somethng with the form tag or somewhere inside javascript

Javascript / Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js?ver=3.0.1"></script>
        <script>

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#submit").click(function(){
                    var email = $("#email").val();  
                    var name = $("Name").val();
                    var subject = $("Subject").val();
                    var text = $("textarea").val();
                    var telephone = $("tel").val();
                    var data = "email : "+email + "name : " + name + "subject : " + subject + "text : "+text + "telephone : " + telephone;
                    console.log(data);
                });
            });
```

HTML :

```
<form action="POST">
                    <label for="email">Email:</label>           
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
                    <label for="Name">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name">
                    <label for="Subject">Subject:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="Subject" id="Subject">
                    <label for="text">Text:</label>
                    <textarea name="text" id="textarea" cols="30" rows="5" ></textarea>
                    <label for="Tel">Telephone:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="Telephone" id="tel">
                    <br><br>
                    <input type="button" value="send" id="submit">  
                </form>
```

Later for this task ill add AJAX script :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $("#submit").click(function(){
                    var email = $("#email").val();  
                    var name = $("Name").val();
                    var subject = $("Subject").val();
                    var text = $("textarea").val();
                    var telephone = $("tel").val();
                    var varData = "email : "+email + "name : " + name + "subject : " + subject + "text : "+text + "telephone : " + telephone;
                    console.log(data);

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: 'sendPHP.php',
                        data : varData,
                        success: function(){
                            alert("message sent");
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
```

and inside sendPHP.php file a code like :

```
<?php 
   $name = $_POST['email'];
   and so on ..
   ..
  ..
mail(something that sends above data to partcularEmail@gmail.com);
?>
```

Comment: What if the user submits using the enter key? that doesn't trigger a click event. Try `$('form_selector').on('submit', function() {//handle submit here });`

Answer (score 1):

You need to prepend a `#` to select an element using it's id.

```
                    var email = $("#email").val();  
                    var name = $("#Name").val();
                    var subject = $("#Subject").val();
                    var text = $("#textarea").val();
                    var telephone = $("#tel").val();
                    var varData = {"email":email,"name":name,"subject":subject,"text":text,"telephone":telephone};
```

And the ajax code should be

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'sendPHP.php',
        data : varData,
        success: function(){
            alert("message sent");
        }
    });
```

Comment: do you know anything about the php code and is the Ajax fine

Comment: See uppdated answer. and if it solves your issue please mark it as a correct answer.

Comment: @Void please check the varData which created by Georgi you just wrapped it with '{}' but it should be valid json while by wrapping in braces is not enough...

Comment: Dude he should totally mark that as correct answer!

Answer (score 1):

replace click function with

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
                    var email = $("#email").val();  
                    var name = $("#Name").val();
                    var subject = $("#Subject").val();
                    var text = $("#textarea").val();
                    var telephone = $("#tel").val();
                    var varData = {"email":email,"name":name,"subject":subject,"text":text,"telephone":telephone};
                    console.log(varData);

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: 'login.php',
                        data : varData,
                        success: function(){
                            alert("message sent");
                        }
                    });
                });
```